# Linear Combine Stones

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Problem: There are $n$ linear piles each containing $a_i$ stones. In each move, Alex chooses two neighboring piles randomly (containing say $A$ and $B$ stones) and combines them to create a single pile with $A +B$ stones at the same place. Such a move yields him $A + B$ points. He does it repeatedly until there is one pile. Alex's score is the sum of all points in $n-1$ moves. What is the expected value of Alex's score?

I am stuck at this, I found that total $(n-1)!$ ways but I couldn't find how many points we get in all possible ways. I know the answer would be a (Total number of points/ no of ways) . But I can't find a way to calculate numerator. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\underline{\text{Overview}}$

Initially, I posted an answer that was wrong, because I overlooked that the OP (i.e. original poster) specified that the coupling is always between **neighboring** piles.

Then, the OP left a comment, following my answer, indicating my mistake.  As a result, I deleted my answer, and left several explanatory comments.

After thinking about the problem, I was finally able to come up with a recursive formula for specifying the expected value.  So, I have deleted my comments and repaired my answer.

A case can be made that the following answer is somewhat inferior, because it requires that recursion be used to compute the expected value.  That is, I was not able to translate the results from recursion into a closed form expression.

Analysis follows:

---

$\underline{\text{Initial Analysis}}$

The problem resolves to determining the *average scalar* that should be associated with each of $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$.

For $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}, ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}:$ 
let $r(n,i)$ denote the average scalar that should be assigned to $a_i$.

For $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ let $E(n)$ denote the expected value.  Then,

$$E(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[r(n,i) \times a_i\right]. \tag1 $$

So, $~r(2,1) = 1, ~r(2,2) = 1$. 
That is, when $n=2$, the expected value is $a_1 + a_2$.

What is needed is a way of computing 
$\{r(n+1,1), r(n+1,2), \cdots, r(n+1, n+1)\}$ 
based on 
$\{r(n,1), r(n,2), \cdots, r(n,n)\}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Consideration of the First Coupling}}$

In considering the computation of $~E(n+1),~$ there are $(n)$ different couplings that could be the very first coupling taken.  These couplings are 
$[a_1:a_2], ~[a_2:a_3], ~\cdots, ~[a_n:a_{n+1}].$

So, there are $(n)$ different cases to consider, depending on which coupling is first.

Assume that the first coupling is $~[a_k:a_{k+1}] ~: ~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.$

Let $s(n+1,i)$ denote the tally that is applied to $a_i$, as a result of the very first coupling (only).

Then, as a result of the first coupling being $~[a_k:a_{k+1}],~$ you have that

- $s(n+1,k) = 1 = s(n+1,k+1).$
- $s(n+1,i) = 0 ~: ~i \not\in \{k,k+1\}.$

Therefore, for all of the $n$ cases combined, you have that

- $s(n+1,1) = 1 = s(n+1,n+1).$
- $s(n+1,i) = 2, ~1 < i < n+1.$

So, the **average** results from this section may be summarized as

$$s(n+1,i) = \frac{1}{n} ~: ~i \in \{1,n+1\}, ~~s(n+1,i) = \frac{2}{n} ~: ~\text{otherwise}. \tag2 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Recursive Consideration of the Subsequent Couplings}}$

As in the previous section, there are $(n)$ cases to consider, depending on which coupling is first.  So, you have to examine all $(n)$ cases, and then determine the average results.

Assume that the first coupling is $~[a_k:a_{k+1}] ~: ~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}.$

At this point, the $(n+1)$ piles, whose original sizes are 
$~a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n+1}$, 
have been converted into $(n)$ piles, whose sizes are now
$~a_1, \cdots, a_{k-1},   \left(a_k + a_{k+1}\right), a_{k+2}, \cdots, a_{n+1}.$

Let $t(n+1,i)$ denote the tally that is applied to $a_i$, as a result of all couplings, **except** the very first coupling.

Then, using recursion, as a result of the first coupling being $~[a_k:a_{k+1}],~$ you have that

- $t(n+1,k) = r(n,k) = t(n+1,k+1).$
- $t(n+1,i) = r(n,i) ~: ~i < k.$
- $t(n+1,i) = r(n,i-1) ~: ~i > k+1.$

Therefore, for all of the $n$ cases combined, you have that

- $t(n+1,1) = n \times r(n,1).$
- $t(n+1,2) = [1 \times r(n,1)] + [(n-1) \times r(n,2)].$
- $t(n+1,3) = [2 \times r(n,2)] + [(n-2) \times r(n,3)].$
- $t(n+1,4) = [3 \times r(n,3)] + [(n-3) \times r(n,4)].$
- $\cdots$
- $t(n+1,n) = [(n-1) \times r(n,n-1)] + [1 \times r(n,n)].$
- $t(n+1,n+1) = n \times r(n,n).$

Therefore, the average value for $t(n+1,i)$ is :

- $\dfrac{n \times r(n,1)}{n} ~: ~ i = 1.$
- $\dfrac{[1 \times r(n,1)] + [(n-1) \times r(n,2)]}{n} ~: ~ i = 2.$
- $\dfrac{[2 \times r(n,2)] + [(n-2) \times r(n,3)]}{n} ~: ~ i = 3.$
- $\dfrac{[3 \times r(n,3)] + [(n-3) \times r(n,4)]}{n} ~: ~ i = 4.$
- $\cdots$
- $\dfrac{[(n-1) \times r(n,n-1)] + [1 \times r(n,n)]}{n} ~: ~ i = n.$
- $\dfrac{n \times r(n,n)}{n} ~: ~ i = n+1.$

If $~r(n,0)~$ and $~r(n,n+1)~$ are both construed to equal $(0)$, then the **average** results from this section may be summarized as

$$t(n+1,i) = \frac{[(i-1) \times r(n,i-1)] + [(n+1 - i) \times r(n,i)]}{n}. \tag3 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Summary of Results and Recursive Chart}}$

In summary, you have that:

- $\displaystyle E(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[r(n,i) \times a_i\right].$
- $r(2,1) = 1 = r(2,2).$
- $\{r(n+1,1), r(n+1,2), \cdots, r(n+1,n+1)\}~$ may be computed from $\{r(n,1), r(n,2), \cdots, r(n,n)\}~$ as follows:
  $\displaystyle s(n+1,i) = \frac{1}{n} ~: ~i \in \{1,n+1\}, ~~s(n+1,i) = \frac{2}{n} ~: ~\text{otherwise}.$ 
  $\displaystyle t(n+1,i) = \frac{[(i-1) \times r(n,i-1)] + [(n+1 - i) \times r(n,i)]}{n}.$ 
  $r(n+1,i) = s(n+1,i) + t(n+1,i).$

**Chart**

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  n & r(n,1) & r(n,2) & r(n,3) & r(n,4) & r(n,5) & r(n,6) \\
  \hline                       
  2 & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  3 & \dfrac{3}{2!} & \dfrac{4}{2!}  & \dfrac{3}{2!} \\
  \hline
  4 & \dfrac{11}{3!} & \dfrac{15}{3!}  & \dfrac{15}{3!} & \dfrac{11}{3!} \\
  \hline
  5 & \dfrac{50}{4!} & \dfrac{68}{4!}  & \dfrac{72}{4!} & \dfrac{68}{4!} & \dfrac{50}{4!} \\
  \hline
  6 & \dfrac{274}{5!} & \dfrac{370}{5!}  & \dfrac{400}{5!} & \dfrac{400}{5!} & \dfrac{370}{5!} & \dfrac{274}{5!} \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

Comment: Why you are using 4! combinations? Alex is randomly choosing only neighboring piles, am I 
 missing something?

Comment: @bigstreet Answer edited.